# Set new object property with Dynamics 365 using Alexa CRM toolkit

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, alexacrm-toolkit

I'm using AlexaCRM Toolkit for Dynamics 365, I added a new field for the entity lead (I created a custom field called new_wordpressid) so I can do the mapping with the lead created in wordpress and the lead in Dynamics 365, when I want to create a new lead using the following code lines:

```
$lead= $service->entity('lead');
$lead->firstname = 'john';
$lead->lastname= 'do';
$lead->new_wordpressid = '555';
$lead->create();
```

I get the following error:

[image]

> Notice: Undefined property via __set() - lead does not support
>   property: new_wordpressid in
>   /var/www/clients/client348/web/wp-content/plugins/dynamics-amcham-crm/dynamics-amcham-crm.php
>   on line 41 in
>   /var/www/clients/client348/web/wp-content/plugins/integration-dynamics/vendor/alexacrm/php-crm-toolkit/src/Entity.php
>   on line 261

Adding the new wordpress_id causes an error. How can I set the wordpress_id Without having any errors?

Comment: How have you "added a new field for the entity lead". I believe that the problem is with the field's declaration.

Comment: the new_wordpressid is created based on the Microsoft Dynamics 365 user interface.

Comment: What type of field is it? Text, number, lookup?

Comment: @jcjr the field type is Text

Comment: Are the customizations published?

Comment: @jcjr yes i publish the customizations ,i still get the same error

Comment: Is line 361 the line setting the property "new_wordpressid" or the line calling "create()"?

Comment: I solved the problem by updating the packege and i reconnect to dynamics crm , now it works perfectly . i think the problem was from the cache.